# TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python

so i am just writing a program that stores the email password onto an txt file and later can reopen it and log in

```
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\o\\other\\python\\python\\else\\account storage")
def main():
    print("enter email")
    email = input(">> ")
    print("password")
    pas = input(">> ")
    file_obj = open("account.txt", "r+")
    file_obj.write(email,pas)
    file_obj.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

after running this error shows "TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)" btw if you helped or even tried to help me its an massive thanks. :)

Comment: `file_obj.write(email,pas)` → `file_obj.write(email);file_obj.write(pas)` or `file_obj.write(email + pas)` or whatever else format you want. Basically, `write` only accepts 1 string, not 2 as explicitly mentioned in that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two main improvements to your code. 1) Use the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to deal with file read/write. 2) use the [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) to specify the line structure.

```
import os

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\o\\other\\python\\python\\else\\account storage")
def main():
    print("enter email")
    email = input(">> ")
    print("password")
    pas = input(">> ")
    with open("account.txt", "r+") as f:
        f.write(f'{email} {pas}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The write method of a file is taking one argument and in this case, 2 was provided
you can try

```
file_obj.write(" ".join([email,pas]))
```

This will comabin but of the values to insert in one line to the file.